# Reflection bool property in LINQ

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to use reflection to write this code better. I now have the `IsSearchable` and `IsEditable` functions, but can I refactor this code to get the part c.Searchable and c.Editable out?

I have 10 functions like this and only need one. The only different part is what bool property to check, `c.Searchable` or `c.Editable`.

```
  bool searchable = conditions
                .Select(c => c.Searchable)
                .SingleOrDefault();

  bool editable = conditions
                    .Select(c => c.Editable)
                    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using reflection is overkill. Assuming you are checking to see if there are ANY conditions in the list that match `Editable` or `Searchable`, you should maybe just use the `Any()` syntax...

You could use a method such as

```
public bool CheckCondition(IEnumerable<Condition> conditions, Func<Condition, bool> predicate)
{
    return conditions.Any(predicate);
}
```

and use it like:

```
var isSet = CheckCondition(conditions, c => c.Editable);
```

But you aren't saving yourself much. You might as well just write the `Any()` every time. For example,

```
var isEditable = conditions.Any(c => c.Editable);
```